# what are the implications of setting an IIS app pool to recycle 24 hours instead of 20 minutes

Tags: iis, application, pool

What are the implications of setting the recyle after xx minutes of inactivity from the default of 20 minutes to 24 hours?

The website has a very low activity level.
We have a vendor component that causes a problem only on the first two calls to the component so I would temporarily extend the timeout to 24 hours to minimize the effect until the component is fixed.

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to hear you say "until the component is fixed."

In short, no, there's not usually any issues with doing so. And if there end up being some, keep your eye on the site and server and tweak as required.

We usually set all sites to recycle once or twice every 24 hours (turning off recycle after x minutes). The only issues you'd run into are all ones that you can deal with on a case by case basis as the need arises (i.e. tweak to allow for more frequent recycling on problem sites, etc.):

1. Your server might not have enough resources (memory) to handle a ton of sites not recycling, which will cause...well, just tweak the problem sites.
2. Other issues not seen before might pop up because frequent recycles have previously hidden the problem before. This isn't a bad thing as you'll either fix that issue, or at least know that you need more frequent recycles to deal with it.

EDIT: I should point out that I completely turn off the "recycle after x minutes inactivity", but schedule a recycle during times of lower activity. You can also deal with problem sites, sites that have issues because of memory leaks or what-have-you leading to needing a recycle to bring memory use back down again, by setting the memory based maximums for the app pool. Of course, this leads to not knowing exactly when the recycles will take place, but at least rogue sites won't effect other sites on the server unnecessarily (and keep an eye on the server logs to see when things are being recycled).